# Blockchain Payment receive api

Tags: blockchain, api

While using blockchain receive payment api, what if some one send less then require fund or some one send extra fund on same one time generated address.

does fund will automatically refund to sender or not ?

what to do if i want to refund that amount back to user who send less fund or double fund on that address?

any one have information regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know which api you are talking about , but i am this much sure that ones your transaction is minned and updated in block you cannot revert it or refund it. Blockchain data is immutable. If you want to restrict your client form sending low or high then you have to use some business logic on backend of your code also using JS logic on front end when user inputs the value will help you alot

Comment: I am talking about blockchain.info receive payment API.

Comment: I have seen on coinpayments.net it's a wallet and when some one send less payment when you are using coinpayments.net api so it's refund that less send amount and transaction status shows canceled and when some one send extra so it's shows it's also refund extra amount

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are taking the payment for. Say it is an ecommerce store accepting btc and the  payment is less than what was asked for, then refund is the only option.

If say this is for some ICO Platform you are making, then you can calculate the corresponding number of tokens for that much amount of btc and complete his transaction. You will obviously have to post a disclaimer for the same when the payment is being initiated.

In case of an exchange, the amount is undecided so this question not relevant there.

As cryptoKTM mentioned it entirely depends on the business logic.